# Flask returns 404 when trying to supply GET parameters to root '/' url

Tags: python, flask

Here is my route: `@app.route('/')`. In it I use `request.args.get('page')` for pagination. But the problem I am having is, if I go to my browser and visit `localhost:5000/?page=2` flask returns a 404. What is the reason for this? It works fine on `localhost:5000` but I want to supply a page. How do I do this?
EDIT: Here is my route:

```
from flaskblog import app
from flaskblog.models import Post # Flask-SQLAlchemy
@app.route('/')
def blog_index():
    page_num = int(request.args.get('page', 1))
    post_data = Post.query.paginate(per_page=10, page=page_num).items
    return render_template('index.html', posts=post_data)
```

And for the data I have a single post.

Comment: I am using debug mode as well.

Comment: Supplement the question with app route in the question for reproducing the error and fixing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my error. In Flask-SQLAlchemy pagination, if nothing is found in a page, it `abort(404)`s. To prevent this from happening I did this:

```
#...
Post.query.paginate(per_page=10, page=page_num, error_out=False).items #the error_out=False part
#...
```

And then I handle the problems on my own such as negative page number, no posts found in page etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, you din't pass in `page` as a parameter into your route;
Second, your route is not designed to handle subsequence page(s).

In order for the route to handle default page 1 and subsequent pages, You specify the route as:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'page': 1})
@app.route('/page/<int:page>/')
def index(page):
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: I do not want it as `example.com/3` for `page=3`, but I want it as `example.com/?page=3`.

Comment: Do what you want. BTW, it will be `example.com/page/3/`.